# getting one matrix from each of the files in a folder and sum the matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to read multiple files in a folder and get one matrix from each of them and sum all of the matrices.
script for reading only one file and it works well(md.MCERunFile Item2d is some modules that existed for data reading):

```
 outfile=md.MCERunfile('/somepath/filename') 
 rn_matrix=outfile.Item2d('IV', 'Rn_C%i')
 Shape=np.shape(rn_matrix)
 rn_matrix_float = np.array([]).reshape(0,55)
 for x in range(Shape[0]):
     row = map(float, rn_matrix[x])
     rn_matrix_float=np.vstack([rn_matrix_float, row])
```

The final output rn_matrix_float is a 32 by 64 numpy array

Now I tried:

```
path = '/somepath/*.xxx' 
files = glob.glob(path)
final_matrix=np.zeros((32, 64))
for j in range(0,len(files)):
     outfile = md.MCERunfile(files[j])
     rn_matrix=outfile.Item2d('IV', 'cut_rec_C%i')
     Shape=np.shape(rn_matrix)
     for x in range(Shape[0]):
         rn_matrix_float = np.array([]).reshape(0,64)
         row = map(float, rn_matrix[x])
         rn_matrix_float=np.vstack([rn_matrix_float, row]) 
     final_matrix=final_matrix+rn_matrix_float
```

I think my mistake is that I have already defined outfile and rn_matrix in the loop, that make every rn_matrix_float to be exactly the same instead of reading data from different files, so the final_matrix is a summation of same arrays. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

An iteration like this

```
 rn_matrix_float = np.array([]).reshape(0,55)
 for x in range(Shape[0]):
     row = map(float, rn_matrix[x])
     rn_matrix_float=np.vstack([rn_matrix_float, row])
```

should be written as a list append

```
 alist = []
 for x in range(Shape[0]):
     row = map(float, rn_matrix[x])
     alist.append(row)
 rn_matrix_float=np.vstack(alist)
```

Appending to a list is faster and easier than repeatedly 'concatenating' arrays.  Actually it could probably be written as a list comprehension, or even a one-line array operation

```
rn_matrix_float = rn_matrix.astype(float)
```

(but that's more of a guess since I haven't tried to recreate your data.)

Similarly I'd be inclined to collect the multi-file case, and do one sum at the end

```
alist2 = []
for j in range(0,len(files)):
     outfile = md.MCERunfile(files[j])
     rn_matrix=outfile.Item2d('IV', 'cut_rec_C%i')
     alist2.append(rn_matrix.astype(float)
final_matrix = np.array(alist2)
print(final_matrix.shape) # check shape
final_matrix = final_matrix.sum(axis=0)
```

If the intermediate array gets too big we might want to add incrementally.  But for a start I think you should become comfortable with accumulating multidimensional arrays, and then 'reducing' them with actions like `sum`.